rust move vec content to another vec sent to routine efficiently
I have a program receiving and dumping data like
let mut vec = vec[]!;
loop {
  let data = socket.recv();
  vec.push(data);
  if vec.size() > 1000 {
      let vec2 = vec.clone();
      vec.clear();
      tokio::spawn(async move { dump_function(vec2); });
  }
}

I think it is not very efficient because of the clone(). Actually, my program is extremely efficiency crucial, the best is to not allocate memory or copy.
How can I do it? Is it that using a two(multiple) switching buffer is the solution. And  very importanly, the loop can't blocked(like blocked by mutex occupation in the dump_function)

You can avoid the clone by on this place but that means allocating in the next round for growing the new Vec; is it ok?

Two buffers are not enough here since you don't wait for the task. You can use a pool of buffers though.

Another note, is socket.recv() async or not? This will affect how you can use a pool.

socket.recv() can be both async or not, there are two versions of it, one is a busy loop, another is tokio @ChayimFriedman

I meant in this loop, is it async or not? And is changing the loop to also accommodate for getting back vecs from the pool acceptable?

It's not async. It is acceptable for getting back vecs @ChayimFriedman

A thought that came to my mind was: why use Vec in the first place? Couldn't you just forward the content from the socket directly using mpsc/mpmc and let the receiver care when to call dump_funtion?

You can have a pool of Vecs at hand to reuse the allocation:
use std::ops::{Deref, DerefMut};
use std::sync::mpsc;

const MAX_CAPACITY: usize = 1001;

struct VecPool {
    vecs: Vec<Vec<Data>>,
}

impl VecPool {
    fn new() -> Self {
        // Create few ready `Vec`s.
        Self {
            vecs: (0..10).map(|_| Vec::with_capacity(MAX_CAPACITY)).collect(),
        }
    }

    fn get(&mut self, tx: &mpsc::Sender<Vec<Data>>) -> DataVec {
        DataVec {
            data: self
                .vecs
                .pop()
                .unwrap_or_else(|| Vec::with_capacity(MAX_CAPACITY)),
            pool_handle: tx.clone(),
        }
    }

    fn put(&mut self, v: Vec<Data>) {
        debug_assert!(v.capacity() >= MAX_CAPACITY);
        debug_assert!(v.is_empty());
        self.vecs.push(v);
    }
}

struct DataVec {
    data: Vec<Data>,
    pool_handle: mpsc::Sender<Vec<Data>>,
}

impl Deref for DataVec {
    type Target = Vec<Data>;

    fn deref(&self) -> &Self::Target {
        &self.data
    }
}

impl DerefMut for DataVec {
    fn deref_mut(&mut self) -> &mut Self::Target {
        &mut self.data
    }
}

impl Drop for DataVec {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        let mut data = std::mem::take(&mut self.data);
        // Drop elements in the spawned task in case it's expensive.
        data.clear();
        // Ignore the case the receiver was dropped.
        let _ = self.pool_handle.send(data);
    }
}

pub fn do_work() {
    let mut pool = VecPool::new();
    let (pool_tx, pool_rx) = mpsc::channel();
    let mut vec = pool.get(&pool_tx);
    loop {
        let data = socket.recv();
        vec.push(data);

        for v in pool_rx.try_iter() {
            pool.put(v);
        }

        if vec.len() >= MAX_CAPACITY {
            tokio::spawn(async move {
                dump_function(vec).await;
            });
            vec = pool.get(&pool_tx);
        }
    }
}

However, you need to benchmark to see if the overhead of the channel is really faster than just allocating a new Vec every time.
You can also try moving loop to pool.put()  under the if vec.len() > MAX_CAPACITY, it may lead to better performance.
The alternative does not need a clone; just do let vec2 = std::mem::take(&mut vec).
It might be possible to get even faster, but this will have to use unsafe.

As you are spawning a task and passing it the data, two buffers will lead to errors if more than one task is created.
You will need to reallocate a buffer at every iteration. You do not need however, to clone the data, then clear it. You can use std::mem::take to pass the current buffer to the new task, then recreate a buffer in the loop. Bonus points if the amount of data you received is bounded, you can use Vec::with_capacity to preallocate a maximum buffer size and avoid the expensive growing of the container.
I imagine you meant Vec::len instead of size.
let mut vec = vec[]!;

loop {
  let data = socket.recv();
  vec.push(data);
  if vec.len() > 1000 {
      tokio::spawn(async move { dump_function(std::mem::take(vec)); });
      vec = Vec::with_capacity(1001);
  }
}


You don't need to call take in your snippet, vec is already moved into the async block.
